# Setting Up Git Within PHPStorm Without Cloning a Repository

Tags: phpstorm

I have a Git repository which has a remote and a local.  I've been working with the local version through PHPStorm for quite some time, but have been using the command line for all Git functionalities.

I'd like to switch to the built-in Git integration within PHPStorm.  When I go to 'VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Git', my only option is to clone and create a new repository.

Is there anyway for me to select the pre-existing git folder that is already within my project root?

Comment: `Settings | Version Control` ?

Comment: @LazyOne That was it.  Feel free to list this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add/alter your VCS settings for already created project at any time via `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Version Control`.